# React-router v4.1.1 working only on dev-server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I am trying to put my react project into the gh-pages. but i found that
the react router won't working surprisingly it won't work when i bundled
the react code. It work just fine in the dev-server

Here are the code from my Main Component and Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import FrontPage from './FrontPage.js';
import Page from './Page.js';
import Courses from './Courses.js'
import Register from './Register.js'
import "../assets/css/index.css";
import { Router, Route ,Switch} from 'react-router'
import { HashRouter,IndexRoute} from 'react-router-dom'

class Main extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Page>
                    <Route exact path = '/' component = {FrontPage} />
                    <Route path = '/course' component = {Courses}/>
                    <Route path = '/register' component = {Register}/>
                </Page>
            </div>
        );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Here are index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route ,Switch} from 'react-router'
import { HashRouter,IndexRoute, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import Main from './components/Main.js';



render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Route path = '/' component = {Main}/>
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

Here mine github for the project

https://github.com/supasonk/ExampleTutor

Updated: I already found the problems. It seems like GitHub page doesn't work well with the BrowserRouter. I getting it to work by using the Hashrouter instead.

Comment: Do you get any error

Comment: No , there are no error message in the console.